# Adding .csv file as resource file and accessing it in the code

Tags: c#

I have a .csv file which i will read using oledb method in my code now i want this .csv file as my resource  file so i have added that file in the resources.
But struct with accessing the resource file from the code, can anyone please help me on this

Thanks

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that your CSV file is embedded as a resource you could access it like this:

```
using (var stream = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.test.csv"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string csv = reader.ReadToEnd();
    // do something with the CSV
}
```

Comment: Thank you darin... but how can i access this file using oledb basically i should be able to select it by "Select * from table"