# Use csv-files added to c# project as source for combolist

Tags: c#, csv, project

I have a combobox which I fill with content from a csv file.

In my project I have a app.config file where I refer to the file like this:

```
<setting name="ListOfThings" serializeAs="String">
<value>List.csv</value>
</setting>
```

I've added the file to the solution, and set the "Copy To Output" option as "Copy Allways", and I've tried setting the "Build Action" to Content/Compile, but I get the following error:

> Error      67           'Project.Properties.Settings' does not contain
>   a definition for 'ListOfThings' and no extension method 'ListOfThings'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Project.Properties.Settings'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

Before I added the csv file to the project, I referenced to the file with a full path "C:\temp\List.csv"*(c:\temp\List.csv)*, which worked.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried without referring to the file in the app.config? I am working with files without writing anything in the app.config file.

Comment: Did you use the VS UI to create the app property?

Comment: Possible duplicate: see "Adding .csv file as resource file and accessing it in the code" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386118/adding-csv-file-as-resource-file-and-accessing-it-in-the-code). Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add the csv-file reference in the Settings.Designer.cs file, now it works properly! Thanks for all suggestions :)

```
  [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]

    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]

    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("List.csv")]

    public string ListOfThings {

        get {

            return ((string)(this["ListOfThings"]));

        }

    }
```